# Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'classpath:logger/logback-spring.xml'

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

I use Spring boot 2.3.0.RELEASE.

application.properties

```sql
spring.profiles.active=dev

logging.config=classpath:logger/logback-spring.xml

logging.file.dir=reception-electronic-docs
logging.file.name.var=reception-electronic-docs.log
logging.file.archive.format.name=reception-electronic-docs.%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log
```

[image]

**Previously this code worked** (Srping boot 2.2.5.RELEASE).

I use multi module structure in the project. But there, the Central pom does not manage the entire project. I create microservices.

During start up an application encounter an error:

```java
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'classpath:logger/logback-spring.xml'
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [logger/logback-spring.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getURL(ResourceUtils.java:137)
```

What are any ideas to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

I add an dependencies

```xml
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

But I don't understand reason.

After I removed the dependency. But my app runs without errors. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Probably a dependency conflict. If you need that dependency and with it the logback fails  to find a file, you should try to see if there is any logback conflict with that dependency and exclude it.